# Issue with Linux find command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I have written a script to create an array of files that are modified more than 1 day back, iterate through the array and delete them interactively. Somehow the script is not working.

Below is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#take input from user for directory
read -p "Please enter the directory path from which you want to remove unused files" path

#create an array of files modified 2 days back
readarray -t files < <(find "$path" -maxdepth 0 -type f -mtime +1)

#remove the files iteratively and interactively
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
 rm -i "$file"
done
```

This script isn't deleting anything. I have some files created on 12th Jan and untouched after that, but they're still there.
Can you please mention if something is missing here?

Comment: Have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167823/finds-exec-rm-vs-delete for alternatives.  Specifically, you might want to investigate `find ... -exec rm {} +`

Comment: You may also try using BASH xtrace for generating more debug information  (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

Answer (score 1):

`-mtime` only considers full days, meaning `+1` means "at least *2* days ago". From [`man find`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

> #### `-atime n`
>
> File was last accessed less than, more than or exactly  *n**24 hours
> ago.  When find figures out how many 24-hour  periods ago the file was
> last accessed, any fractional  part is ignored, so to match `-atime +1`,
> a file has to have  been accessed at least two days ago.
>
> #### `-mtime n`
>
> File's data was last modified less than, more than or  exactly *n**24
> hours ago.  See the comments for `-atime` to  understand how rounding
> affects the interpretation of file  modification times.

You might also want to consider `-exec` of find instead of storing in an array. This will avoid all sorts of problems when your file names contain special characters, such as blanks, newlines, or globbing wildcards:

```
find "$path" -maxdepth 0 -type f -mtime +1440 -exec rm {} +
```

(a day has 1440 minutes (=60*24))